# Cannot create column_list within a heading_1 in Notion API (Appending a block)

Tags: notion-api, notion

I am trying to append a block to a notion page and there is a `heading_1` inside that block that contains `children` which is a column list that consists of 3 columns, I sent a request structured as follows, `heading_1` -> `children` -> first child is a `column_list` and the column_list has `children` of 2 `column`s, yet I am getting the following error.

The child causing the error ->

```
{
           "type" => "column_list",
    "column_list" => {
        "children" => [
            [0] {
                  "type" => "column",
                "column" => {
                    "children" => [
                        [0] {
                                 "type" => "heading_1",
                            "heading_1" => {
                                    "rich_text" => [
                                    [0] {
                                               "type" => "text",
                                               "text" => {
                                            "content" => "H1 Grey",
                                               "link" => nil
                                        },
                                        "annotations" => {
                                                     "bold" => false,
                                                   "italic" => false,
                                            "strikethrough" => false,
                                                "underline" => false,
                                                     "code" => false,
                                                    "color" => "default"
                                        },
                                         "plain_text" => "H1 Grey",
                                               "href" => nil
                                    }
                                ],
                                "is_toggleable" => false,
                                        "color" => "gray"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            [1] {
                  "type" => "column",
                "column" => {
                    "children" => [
                        [0] {
                                 "type" => "heading_1",
                            "heading_1" => {
                                    "rich_text" => [
                                    [0] {
                                               "type" => "text",
                                               "text" => {
                                            "content" => "H1 Brown",
                                               "link" => nil
                                        },
                                        "annotations" => {
                                                     "bold" => false,
                                                   "italic" => false,
                                            "strikethrough" => false,
                                                "underline" => false,
                                                     "code" => false,
                                                    "color" => "default"
                                        },
                                         "plain_text" => "H1 Brown",
                                               "href" => nil
                                    }
                                ],
                                "is_toggleable" => false,
                                        "color" => "brown"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            [2] {
                  "type" => "column",
                "column" => {
                    "children" => [
                        [0] {
                                 "type" => "heading_1",
                            "heading_1" => {
                                    "rich_text" => [
                                    [0] {
                                               "type" => "text",
                                               "text" => {
                                            "content" => "H1 Orange ",
                                               "link" => nil
                                        },
                                        "annotations" => {
                                                     "bold" => false,
                                                   "italic" => false,
                                            "strikethrough" => false,
                                                "underline" => false,
                                                     "code" => false,
                                                    "color" => "default"
                                        },
                                         "plain_text" => "H1 Orange ",
                                               "href" => nil
                                    }
                                ],
                                "is_toggleable" => false,
                                        "color" => "orange"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Error ->

```
{\"object\":\"error\",\"status\":400,\"code\":\"validation_error\",\"message\":\"body failed validation. Fix one:\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].embed should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].bookmark should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].image should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].video should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].pdf should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].file should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].audio should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].code should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].equation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].divider should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].breadcrumb should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].table_of_contents should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].link_to_page should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].table_row should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].heading_1 should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].heading_2 should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].heading_3 should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].paragraph should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].bulleted_list_item should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].numbered_list_item should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].quote should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].to_do should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].toggle should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].template should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].callout should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\\nbody.children[41].paragraph.children[1].heading_1.children[0].synced_block should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\"}"
```

Does this mean `column_list` isn't supported and it's expecting one of the above?

I looked online for the issue and haven't found anything useful, I am expecting the request to pass and the block to be appended correctly.